# Running same function in parallel without blocking rest of the code python

Tags: python, function, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am continuously collecting tweets with twitter streaming API with Python and it runs 24/7. I need to perform some operations for the collected tweets. For this purpose I defined a function which performs the necessary operation on tweets. After I get tweet, I call the function for the operation. My question is that what is the best way to run this function parallel without blocking the tweet collection. I mean, the speed of tweet stream is changable and if it is too fast I do not want to miss tweets while waiting for end of the fuction run. Briefly, I want to collect tweets continiously without waiting by waiting end of the called function operation so I want to perform the function for the text operations parallel.

Thanks.

Comment: How you fetching a new tweet? Can you provide the code?